# No version tab in file properties in Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008

There seems to be no "version" tab in file properties in Windows Server 2008 R2. There used to be a "version" tab in Server 2003 and XP, showing the exe version and "Other version information" that could carry custom fields.

Is there a way to bring this "version" tab back? Or something that would show that same information in Windows Server 2008? The new "Details" tab doesn't show any custom fields that may be attached to the exe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270535/what-is-windows-vistas-equivalent-for-the-version-tab-in-properties) article on stackoverflow. Not sure if that will help you out with your issue but that is the most common. Most exe's and dll's should show the info you are looking for though.

Comment: That is incomplete unfortunately. I have custom properties added to our exes metadata, and the "Version" tab was showing these very conveniently before. I need to see all these custom fields basically, not just a subset.

Answer (score 2):

I found a Shell Extension to re-enable the Version tab for Windows 7 at 
[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118909/Windows-7-File-properties-Version-Tab-Shell-Extens).

You will need to build it yourself using a full (i.e. paid) version Visual Studio C++ 2008 or later but it won't build using the Express version.  The Express version is missing atlbase.h and I searched around but could not get this file from MS' SDKs.  YMMV!